# How to add tooltip description for excel function arguments in Microsoft office.js custom addin

Tags: office-js, office-addins

I have created excel function using Microsoft office.js addin which works as expected.

Now I need to show tooltip description for excel function arguments as shown below in image. Following example Excel function HELLO has 2 arguments and each argument has description defined.
So how can I add this description in Microsoft office.js custom functions is something I need help

I understand Excel-Dna IntelliSense is also a alternative which does provide this solution but how to integrate IntelliSense with office.js is something I cannot understand.

Any solution with Excel-Dna IntelliSense or without will be acceptable.

Following example tooltip is shown using Excel-DNA intellisense :
[image]

If defining description is not possible then a official link from Microsoft will be very helpful which specifies that it is not supported